# ConnectionError: Proxy connection timed out: (Telethon, http proxy)

Tags: python, proxy, ip, telegram, telethon

I can't connect ti telegram with http proxy with telethon.
I am using python 3.10, and afret reading telethon [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/signing-in.html) about how to connect with proxy, i wrote this:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, connection, events
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
import asyncio
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep
import pymorphy2
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
import os, os.path
import python_socks


string = os.getenv('string')
ip = os.getenv('ip')
port = os.getenv('port')
client = TelegramClient(StringSession(string), api_id=os.getenv('api_id'), api_hash= 
os.getenv('api_hash')
                    ,proxy=(python_socks.ProxyType.HTTP, ip, port))
```

But it doesn't work.
After 5 times of `Attempt 1 at connecting failed: ConnectionError: Proxy connection timed out: 10` i get `ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)`

This proxy is working, but not with telethon, please, help

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your proxy is working and you can connect with the same proxy in Telegram Desktop or other clients.

Then `pip list` and make sure the right package is installed:

For Python >= 3.6 : `python-socks[asyncio]`

For Python <= 3.5 : `PySocks`