# Connecting to an HTTP proxy in Telethon results in 'ConnectionError: Proxy connection timed out' - what's the solution?

Tags: python, http, proxy, telegram, telethon

Telethon, http proxy: ConnectionError: Proxy connection timed out

I want to connect to an HTTP proxy in Telethon but I get the error "Attempt n at connecting failed: ConnectionError: Proxy connection timed out." I have tried the solutions suggested in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71668186):

This proxy works fine in my Telegram Desktop.
The python-socks module is also installed.
Here is an example of the proxy configuration:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import getenv

load_dotenv()

cli_args = {
    'session' : f"app",
    'api_id' : getenv('API_ID'),
    'api_hash' : getenv('API_HASH'),
}



try:
    client = TelegramClient(**cli_args)

    client.set_proxy({
        'proxy_type': 'http',
        'addr': 'rotating.example.com',
        'port': 4151,
        'rdns': True
    })
    
    client.connect()
    
    print(client.get_me)
    
    client.disconnect()

except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```